# hover styles should stay onclick on multilevel menu loading dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used the below script to create multilevel megamenu with a lot of customizations.

Below is the JsFiddle link for the same.

[WORKING FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/DL7Xm/)

Below is the CSS code for the same.

```
/* ######### Drop Down DIVs CSS ######### */


.ddsubmenustyle, .ddsubmenustyle div{ /*topmost and sub DIVs, respectively*/
font: normal 13px Verdana;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
list-style-type: none;
background: transparent;
border:none;
border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
border-bottom-width: 0;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 100;
}

.ddsubmenustyle ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
list-style-type: none;
border: 0px none;
}

.ddsubmenustyle li a{
display: block;
width: 170px; /*width of menu (not including side paddings)*/
color: #09519b;
background-color: #d6d6d6;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 8px 0px 8px 13px;

}

* html .ddsubmenustyle li{ /*IE6 CSS hack*/
display: inline-block;
width: 170px; /*width of menu (include side paddings of LI A*/
}

.ddsubmenustyle li a:hover{
font-weight:bold;
background-color:#bfbfbf;
}

/* ######### Neutral CSS  ######### */

.downarrowpointer{ /*CSS for "down" arrow image added to top menu items*/
padding-left: 4px;
border: 0;
}

.rightarrowpointer{ /*CSS for "right" arrow image added to drop down menu items*/
position: absolute;
padding-top: 3px;
left: 100px;
border: 0;
}

/* ######### Marker List Vertical Menu ######### */

.markermenu{
width: 175px; /*width of side bar menu*/
clear: left;
/*position: relative;*/ /*Preserve this for "right" arrow images (added by script) to be positioned correctly*/
position: absolute;
top:136px;

}

.markermenu ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 56px 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
/*border: 1px solid #9A9A9A;*/
}

.markermenu ul li a{
background: #d6d6d6; /*light gray background*/
color: #09519b !important;
display: block;
width: auto;
padding: 8px 0;
padding-left: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
/*border-bottom: 1px solid #B5B5B5;*/
}

.topRound{
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}

.bottomRound{
    border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
}

* html .markermenu ul li a{ /*IE6 hack*/
width: 155px;
}

.markermenu ul li a:visited, .markermenu ul li a:active{
color: #00014e;
}

.markermenu ul li a:hover, .markermenu ul li a.selected{
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color:#bfbfbf;
}


/* ######### Customized Drop Down ULs CSS (inherits from ddlevelsmenu-base.css) ######### */

.blackwhite li a{
background: white;
}

.blackwhite li a:hover{
background: black;
color: white;
}

ul.miniBlocks{width:732px !important; background:#d6d6d6;}
ul.miniBlocks1{width:366px !important; background:#d6d6d6;}
.miniBlocks li{float:left !important;}
.miniBlocks1 li{float:left !important;}

.mattblackmenu a.selected, .ddsubmenustyle li.selected > a {
background: #bfbfbf; /*background of tab with "selected" class assigned to its LI */
color: #09519B;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

The script and css are working fine. When you move on to the navigation items, you can see the mouse over selection with a darker background color and font bold.

Now, this menu is coming dynamically from a js/jsp include file.

What I need is when a user wants to open up a page, onclick of it, the hover style should stay.

For instance,

If you mouse over on JavaScript Reference > Item Folder 5b > Item Folder 5.2b > Sub Item 5.2.1b and when you want to open Sub Item 5.2.1b, onclick of it, when the page relevant to Sub Item 5.2.1b opens, the hover style should stay on click for the user to know that he is on Sub Item 5.2.1b page when he again wants to hover and open another page or see on what page is he on.

Any other ways are welcomed, but should work on my dynamic scenario.

Comment: you need to hover selected menu path to be hovered or just selected item ?

Comment: Both. The hover is already working, but the onclick should also work where the new page opens - @Mohsen

Comment: Shall appreciate down vote but with a reason atleast.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a single page app, then just give the active item an `active` class that you can style as the active item.

Otherwise, you will need to do this server-side. Your CMS/server-side app needs to give a class `active` to the current active menu item.

```
.ddsubmenustyle li a:hover,
.ddsubmenustyle li a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#bfbfbf;
}
```

Comment: No, there are multiple pages and on click of every page, the left menu (which is coming dynamically) opens up that page, so onclick of the menu items, the hover effect should stay onclick and the page too shall load.

Comment: you can try your logic on the fiddle link provided in the question. Thanks. - @MarkSimpson

Comment: @NathanLee Then as I said, you should apply this at the server-side. Any basic content management system will do this for you. If you wrote your own CMS, then you can add the necessary code to add a class to active menu items. That is the best way. 

There is an alternative.. to store the active menu item in a cookie/localstorage and retrieve it on every page load, but that is not a good idea.

Comment: My backend is XML/JSP based, but I believe I cannot make any alterations to it, but is this doable by only javascript? - @MarkSimpson

Comment: I am not a JS coder, so I can't help you with code. However, the idea is basically that when someone clicks on a menu item, you would save the id of that menu item in a cookie. When the new page opens, your javascript would read that cookie, then find the item in the menu and add a class to it eg: 'active'. This would then be styled by your CSS to match the hover style. But for that, you would have to give each menu item a unique ID or class eg: <li id="foo"><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1a</a></li>. That way your javascript has a way of identifying each menu item.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, as I am more of an integrator of JS than JS coder, so need to figure out how to use the logic in the code format. If you want, I can provide you the js (which is already under the externa resouces of fiddle link), so you can point me towards the starting point. Thx - @MarkSimpson